# How to avoid default date(1970-01-01) storing in MySql

Tags: mysql, date

I'm using MySql as database for my project,I've a DOB(date of birth) field in my form its a optional field,So,users may enter or may not enter the value in DOB field.Suppose they won't enter the value in DOB,then 1970-01-01 date is storing in dob column in DB.The default value for DOB column in DB is NULL only.To avoid this,what I've to do ? I'm using PHP for my project.

I'm using ORM,So, I'm inserting as follows

```
$user->dob = date('y-m-d',strtotime($post->dob));
```

Comment: How are you inserting the data into the database in the first place? You need to show us some code.

Comment: which ORM you are using?

Comment: @Mahesh.D: Edit your code into the question.

Comment: this should be handle on server side scripting

Comment: It will be specific to your ORM, but you can likely just do $user->dob = NULL;  (when the value isn't provided)

Comment: I just want to skip to check the condition whether dob is null or not,due to performance sake.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if user input something in DoB field.

```
if (!empty($post->dob)) 
    $user->dob = date('y-m-d',strtotime($post->dob));
```